UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT when calling chainlink function
I am following the example to call a chainlink function. The example works fine when I run it on Ethereum Sepolia. However, I want to deploy it on Polygon Amoy. Once I deploy the smart contract on Polygon Amoy instead, and also set up my new Chainlink subscriptions, and also configuring all the routers, consumer address and so on, the process terminates when attempting to make the request. I did not edit the FunctionsConsumerExample.sol at all. source.js is left untouched, and I only edited the configurations in request.js, along with increasing the gasLimit in sendRequest as such:
 const transaction = await functionsConsumer.sendRequest(
    source, // source
    encryptedSecretsUrls,
    0, // don hosted secrets - slot ID - empty in this example
    0, // version of the encrypted secrets
    args,
    [], // bytesArgs - arguments can be encoded off-chain to bytes.
    subscriptionId,
    400000, // I manually set this to 400000. If left as gasLimit (300000), I'll get this error - transaction underpriced: gas tip cap 1500000000, minimum needed 2500000000
    ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(donId) // jobId is bytes32 representation of donId
  );

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"execution reverted","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas"


Have you also changed the RPC URL corresponding to the Polygon Amoy network, the one used in line 45 of the request.js file?
